# Eigenvalues restricted to a subspace, $\inf_{\|x\| = 1, x \in V} \langle x, P x\rangle$?

Tags: reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

By Courant-Fisher minimax theorem, we know that the bottom eigenvalue of a symmetric real matrix $P$ is given by
$$
\inf_{\|x\| = 1} x^TPx.
$$
Is there a name/theory for 'eigenvalues' when we additionally restrict to a subspace? In particular, I would be interested in the following quantity:
$$
\lambda(P, V) := \inf_{\|x\| = 1, x \in V} x^TPx,
$$
where $V$ is a subspace. Some basic properties are obvious: the infimum is attained (at least in finite dimension) although we clearly no longer have $Pz = \lambda(P, V) z$, at least in general, when $V$ has positive codimension. Finally, if $B$ denotes a basis matrix for $V$, then we have $\lambda(P, V) = \lambda_{\rm min}(B^T P B)$.

Is there anything else to be said about such "eigenvalues"?